# String formatting in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have some problems to format strings from a `List<string>`

Here's a picture of the List values:

[image: pic1]

Now I managed to manipulate some of the values but others not, here's what I used to manipulate:

```
string prepareStr(string itemToPrepare) {
    string first = string.Empty;
    string second = string.Empty;
    if (itemToPrepare.Contains("\"")) {
        first = itemToPrepare.Replace("\"", "");
    }
    if (first.Contains("-")) {
        int beginIndex = first.IndexOf("-");
        second = first.Remove(beginIndex, first.Length - beginIndex);
    }
    return second;
}
```

Here's a picture of the Result:

[image: pic2]

I need to get the clear Path without the (-startup , -minimzed , MSRun , double apostrophes).

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT my updated code:

```
void getStartUpEntries() {

    var startEntries = StartUp.getStartUp();

    if (startEntries != null && startEntries.Count != 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < startEntries.Count; i++) {

            var splitEntry = startEntries[i].Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            var str = splitEntry[1];
            var match = Regex.Match(str, @"\|\|""(?<path>(?:\""|[^""])*)""");
            var finishedPath = match.Groups["path"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finishedPath)) {

                if (File.Exists(finishedPath) || Directory.Exists(finishedPath)) {

                    var _startUpObj = new StartUp(splitEntry[0], finishedPath,
                                                 "Aktiviert: ", new Uri("/Images/inWatch.avOK.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                                                 StartUp.getIcon(finishedPath));

                    _startUpList.Add(_startUpObj);

                }
                else {

                    var _startUpObjNo = new StartUp(splitEntry[0], finishedPath,
                                           "Aktiviert: ", new Uri("/Images/inWatch.avOK.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                                            StartUp.getIcon(string.Empty));

                    _startUpList.Add(_startUpObjNo);
                }
            }

            var _startUpObjLast = new StartUp(splitEntry[0], splitEntry[1],
                                         "Aktiviert: ", new Uri("/Images/inWatch.avOK.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                                          StartUp.getIcon(string.Empty));

            _startUpList.Add(_startUpObjLast);

        }
        lstStartUp.ItemsSource = _startUpList.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You are getting every item doubled. There is the Spotify first without arguments and then with the arguments.

Comment: yeah :) just seen it thanks. Will remove the double entries.

Comment: When you remove the doubles, is it then working fine?

Comment: still getting the same result :(

Comment: What do you mean with same result, the double entries or the arguments? As I can see Raptr and Spotify are working (the rows with the icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract the path:

```
var str = @"0Raptr||""C:\Program Files (x86)\Raptr\raptrstub.exe"" --startup"
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"\|\|""(?<path>(?:\""|[^""])*)""");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["path"]);
```

This will match any (even empty) text (either an escaped quote, or any character which is not a quote) between two quote characters preceeded by two pipe characters.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this regex is not working for me

Comment: @user2649087: I just tested and saw that another capturing group is required to get the desired output. While at it, I will even use a named group to make the following code easier.

Comment: thanks for your code but i cant seem to get it working .                       var str = splitEntry[1];
                    var match = Regex.Match(str, @"\|\|""(?<path>(?:\""|[^""])*)""");
                    var finishedPath = match.Groups["path"];

Comment: @user2649087: what is the content of splitEntry[1]?

Comment: "0Raptr||""C:\Program Files (x86)\Raptr\raptrstub.exe"" --startup" that is the content

Comment: @user2649087: so it must work. What is the content of your `finishedPath` variable after executing that line?

Comment: Please see my updated answer i posted the code up there , i have trouble to debug it because the debugger ignores the regex part while debugging . Im new to C# and im learning :)

Comment: @user2649087: how can it "ignore the regex part while debugging"??? that doesn't make any sense. But judging from your updated question, the content of `splitEntry[1]` is not `0Raptr||"C:\...`, but rather only the path with its arguments, since you've already split on `||` and are only using the second item in the array. If so, you have to either adapt the regex to properly match your provided input, or you have to leave your input as is.

Comment: i know it doesnt make any sense .. but it really ignores it . That seems to be the solution. Thanks very much now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, you could simply split on the double quotes as I see that's a repeating occurrence in your examples and take the second item in the split array:

```
var path = new Regex("\"").Split(s)[1];
```

Comment: This only helps to remove the double apostrophes but the -startup etc stays

Answer (score 0):

This is and update to your logic without using any Regex:

```
private string prepareStr(string itemToPrepare)
{
    string result = null;
    string startString = @"\""";
    string endString = @"\""";

    int startPoint = itemToPrepare.IndexOf(startString);

    if (startPoint >= 0)
    {
        startPoint = startPoint + startString.Length;

        int EndPoint = itemToPrepare.IndexOf(endString, startPoint);

        if (EndPoint >= 0)
        {
            result = itemToPrepare.Substring(startPoint, EndPoint - startPoint);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```